# C# while converting string to byte[] and byte[] to string I got Out of memory Exception

Tags: c#, encryption, compression

I am implementing a system that reads xml files, encrypt and compress them then send to a web service as stream
My test xml files size are differs 1KB to 26MB.
When I run my code as single threaded, it seems working well.
However, when update my code as multi threaded, it is throwing out of memory exception in different part of code while operating large files.

Here is the code block that my code throws exceptions:

1.

```
RijndaelManaged sessionKey = new RijndaelManaged();
sessionKey.KeySize = 256;
EncryptedXml eXml = new EncryptedXml();
byte[] encryptedElement = eXml.EncryptData(xmlDoc.DocumentElement, sessionKey, false);
```

2.

```
EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(xmlDoc.DocumentElement, edElement, false);
```

3.

```
private static string CompressStream(string data)
        {
            byte[] byteData = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            byte[] compressedData = QuickCompression.Compress(byteData, CompressionMethod.Deflated, CompressionLevel.Highest);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(compressedData);
        }
```

in the third part, the code can throw exception any line but especially it is throwing in third line which is

```
Convert.ToBase64String(compressedData);
```

Meanwhile, I am checking my memory via task manager while the code running, it seems that there are lots of available memory to use!

My hypothesis is that, even if there are available memory in total, there is not available memory enough to fit byte array size as unified block.

What do you think about it?

If my hypothesis is right, then

Is there any way to force memory to merge available memory blocks to obtain large available block?
or
Is there any way to force my code to wait until enough available memory to fit byte array size as unified block?

If my hypothesis  is wrong, then 
What can be the problem?

Thanks

**EDIT**

there is a class called [MemoryFailPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx), can it help me to solve my problem?

Comment: If your code fails when going multi-threading, hmmm... it probably means you have a multi-threading issue, not a memory issue. Check your code for synchronization issues (including 3d party like this QuickCompression thing), try to add locks, etc.

Comment: Try profiling your memory usage (not using Task Manager though). That would help you pinpoint if memory is the problem rather than making guesses. And as Simon suggested, you might be having a multi-threading issue.

Comment: Is your multithreaded code calling `CompressStream()`? If so, then by making that method singlethreaded (e.g. by protecting it with `lock`) you might be able to fix the problem.

Comment: I rerun my code by adding lock, It seems better now, 
before I added lock, I got exception for 10 file. But now I got exception for 3 files which are top 3 largest files

Comment: I updated my code again.
Previously I locked the function block that encrypt and compresses,
Now, I added a lock before encrypt and release lock after encrypt finished, then I added a lock compress block and release lock after compress finished.
The result is worst!!
So again, I think that it is really memory block problem!

Comment: CompressStream() was a poorly named function.  It should really be named CompressUsingLotsOfVirtualMemoryThatMakesMyProgramCrash().  And yes, using multiple threads is a good way to use a lot more memory.  Not a good way to speed up programs that are actually I/O bound.  Change the projects Platform Target setting to AnyCPU for a possible quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it’s the `new string` inside the `Convert.ToBase64String`.

I maybe have a similar problem. Simply allocating huge memory blocks with `new string` throws out of memory exceptions. On my box (8 GB main memory) at 170 MB and up.